# Unable to pass custom header using perl module HTTP::Request::Generator

Tags: perl

I'm using `atom` and testing out `HTTP::Request::Generator` PERL module. Code , below works on most part but I'm unable to send cookies or headers, it only displays default headers even when I have set in my code.

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use HTTP::Request::Generator 'generate_requests';
use LWP::UserAgent;

my $ua = 'LWP::UserAgent'->new;

my $gen = generate_requests(
    method  => 'GET',
    host    => [  'https://abc.ai/' ],
    pattern => 'https://abc.ai',

    headers => {
        "User-Agent" => 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64',
        "Cookie" => '_abc',
    },
    wrap    => sub {
        my ( $req ) = @_;
        # Fix up some values
        $req->{'headers'}{'Content-Length'} = 666;
    },
    wrap => \&HTTP::Request::Generator::as_http_request,
);

while ( my $req = $gen->() ) {
    my $response = $ua->request( $req );
    # print $response->protocol, ' ', $response->status_line, "\n";
    print $req->headers->as_string, "\n";
    print $req->as_string();
    # Do something with $response here?

    if ($response->is_success) {
        #  print $response->decoded_content;
        print $response ->header('title');
    }
    else {
        die $response->status_line;
    }
}
```

**Output**
`User-Agent: libwww-perl/6.31`
`Login`

The `title` page indicate me I'm not logged in this cookie is fine and i have tested it using `curl` i can manually login and retrieve required resource. Why its failing for perl, how can access my header options in code above. Thanks.

**Solution**

```
body_params => {
       comment => ['Some comment', 'Another comment, A++'],
   },
```

Got it solved adding above code.

Comment: I've tidied the indentation of your code. You're welcome, but please consider doing it yourself next time. Careful indentation is a powerful tool to help people understand your code and if you're asking a group of strangers to read and understand your code it's only polite to make that as easy as possible for them.

Comment: @DaveCross I agree, sorry for inconvenience, I be careful next time

Comment: There is a bug in `as_http_request()`: it will discard your headers unless `body_params` were passed to `generate_requests()` try to add a dummy `body_params => {comment=>['test']},` and you will at least get a HR object that contains your headers. I'm seeing more issues though eg content_length ending up as an aref.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't provide the same option (`wrap`) twice:

```perl
    wrap    => sub {
        my ( $req ) = @_;
        # Fix up some values
        $req->{'headers'}{'Content-Length'} = 666;
    },
    wrap => \&HTTP::Request::Generator::as_http_request,
```

This may work though:

```perl
    wrap    => sub {
        my ( $req ) = @_;
        # Fix up some values
        $req->{'headers'}{'Content-Length'} = 666;
        
        return HTTP::Request::Generator::as_http_request( $req );
    },
```

Also the `headers` option appears to take an arrayref of hashrefs, like this:

```
    headers => [
        {
            "User-Agent" => 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64)',
            "Cookie" => '_abc',
        },
    ],
```

I guess the reason for that is so you can provide alternative sets of headers:

```
    headers => [
        {
            "User-Agent" => 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64)',
            "Cookie" => '_abc',
        },
        {
            "User-Agent" => 'Mozilla/1.0 (Hoover Vacuum Cleaner)',
            "Cookie" => '_def',
        },
    ],
```

That way your request generator can generate two requests for each page, using different `User-Agent` strings, or different cookies (so logged in as different users), or different `Accept` headers, or whatever.

Comment: i did tried and got same response `User-Agent: libwww-perl/6.31
User-Agent: libwww-perl/6.31 Login` i feel like its ignoring the headers all the way

Comment: Your ankylosis is spot on, yes the module is basically HTTP request pattern generator so there is a valid reason to use this syntax as you said e.g two request per page. Let me try this new code.